# Aggregation API: Yodlee transactions resulting when a check bounces

Tags: yodlee

How do people deal with the situation of bounced checks when getting Yodlee transactions through the Aggregation API?
Our app only retrieves posted transactions and it has led to an issue.

Most banks seem to balance the bounced check situation by providing posted transactions for both the initial check disbursement (negative amount) and for the bounced check (positive amount). Bank of America, however only posts the positive amount transaction - (the one the increases the balance of the consumer's bank account) - the original transaction never gets past the pending stage. and since the original transaction (the check) is never posted it results in an incorrect increase in balance on the consumer side.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you are customer of Yodlee, then you can reach out to Yodlee's support team and raise your issue with details like BankName, SiteId,memSiteAccId and cobrandId. Yodlee's data team will look into it and would be able to help you out.